# How do I remove an unintended "flagged item"?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I (apparently) flagged an item as "offensive" by accident. I tried clicking on that link again, only to flag it twice, instead.

How do I remove the two flags from this item. It is a [good post](http://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/?sort=inbox&section=flags), and not offensive at all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9263/how-do-i-remove-an-unintended-%22flagged-item%22?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There looks to be no way to do that at the moment.  I found upstream documentation of this here http://askbot.org/en/question/195/how-do-i-display-all-flagged-questions

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-02**:
Seems to be fixed now with the current answers.ros.org software.